# how $3i \times 3i = 9i \times i$? (i is the unit vector and $\times$ is cross product)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, cross-product

$i$ is the unit vector; didn't know how to write it.

I'm reading a text and somewhere it uses something like $ai \times bi = (ab)i \times i$ (implicitly). I can see why this is true geometrically, but the text says "by distributive law". Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: In my mind, $3i$ is short for $3\cdot i$, so $3i\cdot3i=3\cdot i\cdot3\cdot i=9\cdot i\cdot i$ by the commutativity and associativity of multiplication.

Comment: @JoelBosveld: In this context, multiplication is not commutative.

Comment: @TonyK, I read $i$ as the unit imaginary number. I suppose $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the cross product is intended, based on the answer by phy_math.

Comment: @Joel Bosveld, I taged it multivariable-calculus not imaginary numers :| .

Comment: $i \times i = 0$, so this is not the best example of the distributive law.

Answer (score 0):

Is the $\times$ means the cross product?
In usual vector operation, we have two kinds of operations, (inner, outer(or so called cross) products).

For basis(kinds of unit vector) $\mathbb{e}_i$, the scalar product just changes its scale of vector. 
but its vector product(i mean inner, cross product) changes its direction(inner products gives the scalar, and cross products gives the vector).

$i.e$  (assume we are in $R^3$)

For $\vec{A}=a_i\mathbb{e}_i$ and $\vec{B}=b_i\mathbb{e}_i$

For inner product between them

$ \vec{A}\cdot \vec{B} =a_ib_j(\mathbb{e}_i \cdot \mathbb{e}_j)=a_ib_j \delta_{ij} =a_i b_i$

and for the cross product 
$ \vec{A} \times \vec{B} =a_i b_j (\mathbb{e}_i \times \mathbb{e}_j)=\epsilon_{ijk}a_ib_j\mathbb{e}_k$

Note the operation for vectors only applied for vectors, and operation for scalar only applied for scalars.

If you know furthermore, please look for a any vector calculus algebra textbook, or you can see the explain on wikipedia (i.e http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product in section Properties, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product in section Computing the cross product)

Comment: yes $\times$ means the cross product. but sorry i don't get your answer, i just learned about cross products.

Comment: In above notation $a_i$ and $b_i$ are scalars associate with unit vector $\mathbb{e}_i$, so what i want to say is when you acts on operation, you can acts separately on scalars and vectors. The symbol i used in above seems little bit difficult for beginners, in that sense i feel sorry.

Comment: Furthermorem, cross product on the same vector itself vanishes,  $i.e$ $\vec{A}\times \vec{A}=0$